# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'MenuItemsProps'.ts(2339)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm started learning TypeScript and as of moment I'm converting my React code into TypeScript. Then I have run into this issue I couldn't fix it. Basically I'm passing a state through props component that have implemented value, and hoping this state will be recognize on the other component but then I'm getting error when I tried to map the state on the other component.

Error from MenuItems.tsx:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'MenuItemsProps'.ts(2339)

Error from Project.tsx

> Type 'ClassType[]' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<ClassType[]>>'.
> Type 'ClassType[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: SetStateAction<ClassType[]>): void'.ts(2322)

Here's the code:
Project.tsx

```
import Data from '@/assets/data/Data'

const Project = () =>  {

    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState<typeof Data>(Data); 

    return (
         <MenuItems menuItems={menuItems} />  // Error here in menuItems
    )
}
```

MenuItems.tsx

```
import Data from '@/assets/data/Data'
type MenuItemsProps = {
    menuItems: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ClassType[]>>
}

const MenuItems = (menuItems: MenuItemsProps) => {
    return (
        <div className='menuitem'>
            <h1>sample</h1>
            {
                menuItems.map((item: ClassType) => {   // the Error is coming from map
                    return <div className='menuitem-list' key={item.id}>
                                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                           </div>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Data.ts

```
import { ClassType } from "../types/Types";
const portfolios: Array<ClassType> = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Example1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Example1',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Example1',
    },
]
export default portfolios;
```

Types.ts

```
export type ClassType = {
    id: number,
    title: string,
}
```

So what I have tried to use the Dispatch and SetStateAction but unfortunately it was no help

--- EDIT ---

The issue has been resolve with the help from the comment below:
I have added curly bracket on  { menuItems }:

> const MenuItems = ({ menuItems }: MenuItemsProps) => {

Then replace this "React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ClassType[]>>" with ClassType[] which the issue:

> type MenuItemsProps = {
> menuItems: ClassType[]
> }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full text of the error you are getting.

Comment: @HereticMonkey , just added the error display. Here its is as well: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'MenuItemsProps'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

Replace "menuItems.map" with "Data.map". You are currently trying to map a props object.

Comment: Hi, that what I'm trying to do, and it was working with React but when I have change it in Typescript, it won't let me. It sending me an error on the map() function. Also when I tried to display menuItems.map in the Project.tsx, it has no issues at all! Only when I'm passing to props to another component is making some error

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. <s>There is some invalid JSX: `<h2>` is missing its closing tag.</s> Looks that was just a copy/paste error and has been corrected in an edit.
2. `menuItems` is the props object. Any props you pass to your components will be given as properties of that object. To access the `ClassType[]` that the Project component is giving to MenuItems, you need to access the `menuItems` property of that object. Thus, you would either have to access it as `menuItems.menuItems` or [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) it:

```
menuItems.menuItems.map((item: ClassType) => {...})
// or
const MenuItems = ({ menuItems }: MenuItemsProps) => {...}
```

3. Finally, the actual TypeScript issue: you are declaring that `menuItems` prop to be `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ClassType[]>>`, but that's a type for a function, not an array (specifically, it's the type of the `setMenuItems()` function in `Project.tsx`). Based on what you're giving MenuItems in the Project component, you really just want that to be the following:

```
type MenuItemsProps = {
    menuItems: ClassType[]
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works fine! So basically I did what you said on #3, and the add curly bracket as well on the { menuItems } OR "const MenuItems = ({ menuItems }: MenuItemsProps) => {" Thanks for the help!!! I'm still leaning Typescript so its rookie mistake